# r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$ URL 404ing

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to use this link `<a href="Annotation/{{ vod.id }}">` to load another page in my website base on primary key of videos. My url file is as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Vod.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:25], template_name="Annotation/home.html")),

    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Vod.objects.get(pk=1).posts.all().order_by("-date"), template_name="Annotation/post.html")),
]
```

I get the standard 404 from the links generated using the aforementioned link.

Thanks!

edit: Added the base URLs

```
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^Annotation', include('Annotation.urls')),
url(r'^Profile', include('Profile.urls')),
```

This is the URL for Profile.urls

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

edit2: Changed URL and added view I'm trying to use.

```
url(r'^(?P<key>[0-9]+)$', views.post, name="post")
```

Here's views.post

```
def post(request, key):
try:
    target_vod = Vod.objects.get(pk=key)
except Target.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Vod does not exist")
target_posts = Vod.objects.get(pk=key).posts.all().order_by("-date")
context = {'target_vod': target_vod, 'target_posts': target_posts}
return render(request, 'Annotation/post.html', context)
```

Comment: You can start here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/

Comment: Please include the base urls.py where you're including these URLs. It's important to see how the URLs are stacking.

Comment: `Annotation/id != /id`, how is it supposed to match?

Comment: Okay I added the base URLs as well

Answer (score 0):

I have seperated the code and put it into a views.py. This should work.

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', AnnoList.as_view(), template_name="Annotation/post.html")),
```

Then in views.py:

```
class AnnoList(ListView):

    template_name = 'Annotation/post.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.vod = get_object_or_404(Vod, pk=self.args[0])
        return Posts.objects.filter(vod=self.vod).all().order_by("-date")
```

I assuming here that you have two different tables and that Posts has a foreign key to Vod.

Comment: If you look at my second edit, I implemented something similar to this. However, I'm still getting a 404.

Comment: Try to debug. Implement 'print(key)' at some points to see where the problem is. Also, is that record available anyway?If you don't have a Vod record in your database with that pk, you will always get a 404 error.